# MATLAB variable contour LevelStep

Tags: matlab, contour

I know the contours that I want to display in my contour plot, but they are not regularly spaced.  Is it possible to manually enter these contour values instead of just a LevelStep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the [contour documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f10-2524.html#f10-2600) right before it talks about `LevelStep`, it also says (I skipped out some bits that were about specifying the number of contour levels, which you already know about):

> The contouring functions permit you to specify the number of contour levels or the particular contour levels to draw. In the case of `contour`, ... `contour(Z,v)`. `Z` is the data matrix, ... and `v` is a vector of specific contour levels.

So just do (e.g.)

```
contour(Z,[1 2 3 4 5]) % or contour(X,Y,Z,v)
```

which will plot `Z` with contour lines at 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.